# Colab IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, arrays, bounds, index-error

My project  aims to segment handwritten documents to line using A* algorithm , But i face this error at this code .

```
def group_the_road_blocks(road_blocks):
    #group the road blocks
    road_blocks_cluster_groups = []
    road_blocks_cluster = []
    size = len(road_blocks)
    for index, value in enumerate(road_blocks):
        road_blocks_cluster.append(value)
        if index < size-1 and (road_blocks[index+1] - road_blocks[index]) > 1:
            road_blocks_cluster_groups.append([road_blocks_cluster[0], road_blocks_cluster[len(road_blocks_cluster)-1]])
            road_blocks_cluster = []

        if index == size-1 and len(road_blocks_cluster) > 0:
            road_blocks_cluster_groups.append([road_blocks_cluster[0], road_blocks_cluster[len(road_blocks_cluster)-1]])
            road_blocks_cluster = []

    return road_blocks_cluster_groups

binary_image = get_binary(img)

for cluster_of_interest in hpp_clusters:
    nmap = binary_image[cluster_of_interest[0]:cluster_of_interest[len(cluster_of_interest)-1],:]
    road_blocks = get_road_block_regions(nmap)
    road_blocks_cluster_groups = group_the_road_blocks(road_blocks)
    #create the doorways
    for index, road_blocks in enumerate(road_blocks_cluster_groups):
        window_image = nmap[:, road_blocks[0]: road_blocks[1]+10]
        binary_image[cluster_of_interest[0]:cluster_of_interest[len(cluster_of_interest)-1],:][:, road_blocks[0]: road_blocks[1]+10][int(window_image.shape[0]/2),:] *= 0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0bce745f6c12> in <module>()
     71     for index, road_blocks in enumerate(road_blocks_cluster_groups):
     72         window_image = nmap[:, road_blocks[0]: road_blocks[1]+10]
---> 73      binary_image[cluster_of_interest[0]:cluster_of_interest[len(cluster_of_interest)-1],:][:, road_blocks[0]: road_blocks[1]+10][int(window_image.shape[0]/2),:] *= 0

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

The refrence for hole code : https://github.com/muthuspark/line-segmentation-handwritten-doc/blob/master/A*%20Path%20Planning%20Line%20Segmentation%20Algorithm.ipynb

The error appears at : In[6]

Comment: What happened when you tried to check the contents of `binary_image`? Does it look like what you expect? If it doesn't look like what you expect, what happened when you tried to diagnose that problem? If `get_binary` is not your own code, what happened when you tried to read the documentation? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: this variable will be used later , but as it becomes error i could not run the other cell

Comment: That does not answer my question.